# Secure Token Service with a Separate public login page

Tags: c#, wif, sts-securitytokenservice

It's been quite a while now that I am working with the STS and RP thing. Now I have an issue that I want a separate web application which will contain a single login page, where my applications will be redirected if they dont have the federated cookie. Please let me know if its possible by using the . So far I have redirected the Relying party to the application which has a single login page and this FederatedPassiveSignIn control on it. Now when I click this control it gets redirected to the STS login page which is what I dont want. I want to get access from here and get back to the application requesting for the authentication.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So you want to write an STS?

There are some simple templates in the WIF SDK - or you use IdentityServer as a starting point:
http://thinktecture.github.com/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v2/